# Multiple OneTimeWorkRequests with delay as chain

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I'm making an app Medicine Reminder that should remind about medicine consuming based on dates and hours saved in database.
Reminding should occur in form of notification.
Let's assume that I have one medicine that should be consumed twice (for quick testing for example at 9:50 pm and 9:55 pm). Notifications are triggered with button click.

My problem - only the first notification will be displayed and the other ones don't.

This is my code:

```
public void makeNotifications(Date now, String[] medicineNames, Date[] 
takingTime) {

    WorkContinuation continuation = null;

    for (int i = 1; i < medicineNames.length + 1; i++) {

        Data.Builder dataBuilder = new Data.Builder()
                .putString(MEDICINE_NAME_KEY, medicineNames[i - 1])
                .putLong(MEDICINE_TAKING_TIME_KEY, takingTime[i - 1].getTime());
        OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder requestBuilder =
                new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class)
                        .setInputData(dataBuilder.build());

        if (i == 1) {
            long diff = Math.abs(takingTime[i - 1].getTime() - now.getTime());
            requestBuilder.setInitialDelay(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            continuation = mWorkManager.beginUniqueWork(
                    MEDICINE_NOTIFICATION_KEY,
                    ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                    requestBuilder.build());
        } else {
            long diff = Math.abs(takingTime[i - 1].getTime() - now.getTime());
            requestBuilder.setInitialDelay(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            continuation.then(requestBuilder.build());
        }
    }
    continuation.enqueue();
}
```

Do you have any suggestion/explanation/solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WorkManager` is not the best solution for your usecase, since you need some trivial job to be done at **specific time**. `WorkManager` will respect the doze mode conditions and your notifications won't be posted if device is in doze mode.

I would recommends you to use `AlarmManager` instead. Either use `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` or `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` of AlarmManager

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby):

> Standard AlarmManager alarms (including setExact() and setWindow())
>   are deferred to the next maintenance window.
>
> - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
> - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.